# Cannot resolve state error in ui-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in route.js

```
.state('app', {
        url:'/app',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/index.html'
      })

      .state('app.sales', {
        url:'/app/sales',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/sales.html'
      })
```

Then this is my view

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li ui-sref="sales">Sales</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

When I clicked on the li, in my console I saw this error `Could not resolve 'sales' from state 'app'`

What's wrong? I'm trying to use nested view. I want my sidebar to remain and the content change dynamically.

Comment: Is you question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'app.sales' state name instead in ui-sref

Answer (score 1):

You want to go to the `app.sales` when putting up a ui-sref on anchor tags.
So, you'd do it like this :

```html
<li><a ui-sref="app.sales">Sales</a></li>
```